# Комбинирование Get- и PostMapping в Spring Boot

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, axios

Мне нужно принимать POST-запрос от игрового сервера, парсить его ответ и потом отправлять Json на фронт(React). Как я могу это реализовать?
В коде выше описанное выглядит так:

```java
@PostMapping
@GetMapping("")
public String[] getPost(@RequestBody String input){
   //парсим, результат в массив и отправляем
}
```

Но так я получаю `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'`. Если убрать `@PostMapping` и `@RequestBody String input`, то это работает, чтоб отправлять данные на React. Но тогда я не могу получать данные с игрового сервера. Как-то можно скомбинировать PostMapping и GetMapping? Или лучше просто перенести парсер на React и отправлять логи сразу туда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По феншую, у вас должно быть два отдельных метода. Метод GET не предусматривает тела и для него @RequestBody вызывает то, что вызывает.

```java
@GetMapping("")
public String[] getSomeone(){
   //парсим, результат в массив и отправляем
}
@PostMapping("")
public String[] postSomeone(@RequestBody String input){
   //парсим, результат в массив и отправляем
}
```

Но, если нельзя, но очень хочется, то можно :)

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
public String[] getSomeone(HttpServletRequest request){
  //Обрабатываем реквест в зависимости от его типа
}
```